# Declaration of IntRect SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm working on a project in `SFML`and I would like to set the position of a rectangle on my sprite sheet using a `std::pair`. In my `.hpp` I have this attribut.
`sf::IntRect _size;` which is use to set the `width, height, x, y` of the rectangle.
In my `.cpp`file, I've done this.

```
void Character::setCharacter(const std::string& texture_p, std::pair<float, float> rec, std::pair<float, float> recc)
{
    _size = {rec.first, rec.second, recc.first, recc.second};

    if (!_texture->loadFromFile(texture_p))
        throw CharacterError(ERR_TEXTURE, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    _sprite->setTexture(*_texture);
    _sprite->setTextureRect(_size);
}
```

but during the compilation, I have this error and I don't know its meaning.

```
Element '1': conversion from '_Ty1' requires a narrowing conversion
Element '2': conversion from '_Ty2' requires a narrowing conversion
Element '3': conversion from '_Ty1' requires a narrowing conversion
Element '4': conversion from '_Ty2' requires a narrowing conversion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means you're implicitly converting from float to int which can cause a loss of precision.

Explicitly convert the elements from float to int:

```
_size = {
    static_cast<int>(rec.first),
    static_cast<int>(rec.second),
    static_cast<int>(recc.first),
    static_cast<int>(recc.second)
};
```

Or change `rec` and `recc` to be `std::pair<int, int>` in the first place.